# can not find application in android market when searching and application is not compatible

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

I uploaded my application 12 hours ago. Until now, I can not find my application when searching in the android market. I can only see it when enter details?id=my.application. But in this case, it is not compatible with any device. I have uploaded a quite similar application with the same permission, but the second one work well.

Could anybody explain to me what happen. Or do I have to continue waiting?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a read through the [Market Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html) document. The causes of this are too many to list, but I'll highlight the main ones:

- `<supports-screens>`
- `<uses-configuration>`
- `<uses-feature>`
- `<uses-permission>`
- `<uses-sdk>`

To summarize, go through your `AndroidManifest.xml` file again and ensure it's targeting the correct API levels, etc.

Comment: Well, I absolutely know that my androidmanifest has no error because it is nearly same one application I ve added before... are there any reasons else...

Comment: @detno29 I didn't say your `AndroidManifest.xml` had an error in it :) I only meant go through all the options you set again and ensure that any _feature_, _screen_, etc you set is compatible with the device you're trying to get it installed on.

Comment: Yes I understand what you re meaning. But I have tested with several devices,and all of them do not work...:( in additional, it is OK if I sign this application with the same key I used for my last application?

Comment: @detno29 As far as I'm aware, you're _supposed_ to sign each app with the same key. The purpose of the key to identify _you_ as the developer. Now if _none_ of the devices you tested are _compatible_ with your app (as determined by Android Market), then yes, you have an extraneous option set in your manifest that you need to get rid of. Again, go through all the parameters in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file :)

Comment: ok thanks alot, and thanks for your suggestion. Finally, my application is on the market and it is compatible...^^